# Address already in use - bind(2) for 178.62.19.65:80 (Errno::EADDRINUSE), how do I restart unicorn on port80

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, server, unicorn

I have done few alterations to my database but it is not reflected when I restart rails server. I use

```
 sudo service unicorn stop
```

and

```
 sudo service unicorn start
```

Unicorn starts but when I run the following line of code,

```
 root@moneytree:/home/zhall/zoulfia# rails s -p80 -e 
     production --   binding=moneytree.space
```

I get:

```
  => Booting Unicorn
   => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production     
  on http://moneytree.space:80
  => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
  => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
  E, [2015-07-11T09:34:29.299617 #30491] ERROR -- 
  : adding listener failed addr=178.62.19.65:80 (in use)
  E, [2015-07-11T09:34:29.300071 #30491] ERROR -- 
  : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)
  .........
  ...........
  Exiting
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems
  /unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:185:in `bind': 
  Address already in use - bind(2) for 178.62.19.65:80 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Why doesn't unicorn port80 get refreshed?  Any help would be very, very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do is to set the 'preload_app' to  'false' in my /etc/unicorn.config file. After that changes to application code were reflected when unicorn were restarted.

Answer (score 0):

There's a program already running on port 80. Check with netstat `netstat -ntl | grep -w 80`. If you see a line with LISTEN then the port is already being used. Alternatively you could run rails on a different port as follows: `rails s -p 8080 -e production`

Comment: It is my program that is running. The question is ,how do I restart it so that I can see the changes done to my website.